# Unable to import modules in pycharm in spite being installed in the used python interpreter

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Even after installing dash - getting module import error.
Pycharm does not throw any compilation errors on the line as well.

How could this be resolved?

[image]

Comment: It's likely your run configuration is using a different interpreter from the one you are showing.

Comment: @bad_coder - any clues as to why that might be happening as i have fixed this interpreter

Comment: Because you configured the wrong interpreter in run configurations. Are you asking how that happened? When you run or debug the interpreter that you configured in the settings for the project (like you're showing in the screenshot) is set on the run configuration, but afterwards if you change the interpreter in the settings the run configuration keeps the interpreter it was originally created with (you'll have to update it in the run configurations manually, or delete the run configuration, there's no way to automatically sync the changes for a run configuration that's already been created).

Comment: Other than that you might have [set the template wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65852787) but if your first execution is using the keyboard or icons on a given module it will auto-configure from the settings [see also this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66193923).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried everything as suggested in comments and stuff known to me but could not resolve this - have done this a thousand times earlier but don't know what went wrong this time.

The only solution the=at worked was to create a new project, copy files over manually and then create a fresh interpreter and VE.